# Split cell then Vloop then sum

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a google form linked to a google sheet.
There is one multiple choice checkbox question in the form that asks the user to check A, B, C.
In the google sheet, the answer are concatenated with a come like this: `A,B,C`

My goal is to give score to each combination of answer using a score sheet.

What is the formula that I can use to achieve that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Google Spreadsheets is out of scope on this site..but a quick possible solution. See if this works for you.

See the below screenshot.

Formula in D2 is...and drag it down up to the intended rows

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(vlookup(transpose(split(C2,",")),$F$2:$G$4,2)))
```

The formula without the Function Name ArrayFormula can be converted to Array Formula by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

[image]

TRANSPOSE function is optional. Just SPLIT should also wotk.